# IndexError: list assignment index out of range [python + selenium]

Tags: python, selenium

```
lin_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr"))

nomes = [lin_count]
for x in range(1, lin_count):
    nomes[x] = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr["+str(x)+"]/td[2]").text)

driver.close()
```

OUT: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Line `nomes = [lin_count]` won't make a list of 5 elements, do like this:

```
nomes = [""] * lin_count
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of problems in your code

1. code

   nomes = [lin_count]

does not create an list with lin_count empty elements. It creates list with one element: lin_count

2. `range(1, lin_count)`
   create list with values from 1 to lin_count-1, so you will miss last element in your list
3. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` returns list already, use it!

I think your code shoud be more like this:

```
nomes = []
x = 0
xpath = "/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr"
for step in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    x += 1
    nomes.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath+"["+str(x)+"]/td[2]").text)
```